# Combination of find and grep command with exec option

Tags: shell, find

I am trying to find all files inside /lib /lib64 folders that contain "lib" in their names and print that file names without extensions (.so or similar), avoiding identical names in output.

My way is: `find /lib /lib64 -name "lib" -exec grep-Ev "*.[a-z]{2}" {} \;`

I am stuck. It doesn't work. It would be grateful to hear any proposes!

Comment: Your first issue is the you need `-name "*lib*"`. or just `"lib*" if you want them just starting with _lib_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /lib* ! -type d -name \*lib\* | cut -d. -f1 | sort -u
```

So, the above command should work for filenames that do not contain newlines, otherwise you'd need to do some more explicit tests. As written, this command locates and file with a name that matches the *`\*lib\*`* glob and it does so *at any depth* - it will recursively search all child directories of the base trees returned by the `/lib*/` glob.

`find` just prints its output - that's what it does. When you `-exec` another command, though, it passes the filenames as arguments to that command, and so you don't `grep` the file *names* but the file *contents* in your command.

So here we parse `find`'s output in a pipeline. `cut` will print up to the first period it finds on any of its input lines, and `sort` will take those results and squeeze any repeats down to a single `-u`nique record per.

Comment: Just curious, what was the reason for using `! -type d` instead of `-type f`?

Comment: @rubyonrails - well, maybe you're not looking for a regular file, but you're almost definitely not looking for a directory.

Comment: The requester specifically said "I am trying to find all files inside /lib /lib64." In your opinion what would constitute something that is not a directory and not a regular flle -- I guess an _irregular file_ -- especially within those directories?  I'm not trying to be nitpicky; I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: @rubyonrails - there are lots of kinds of files, and a regular file is only one kind. `cd /tmp; mkfifo pipe; find . ! -name . -prune -type f`.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /lib /lib64 -name '*lib*' -type f | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/' | xargs -n 1 basename | sort -u
```

Find all files in the lib directories. Strip off anything following the last period. Pass the list to basename to remove the directory name. Sort and remove duplicates.

Comment: It works-for sure!but can it work with using just grep and find?

Comment: @Nitro84 - see my answer. `grep` is not the answer here. You need `sed` or `awk` for this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are wanting only filenames without any type of extensions.  If you are looking for a single pipe to knock this out, `grep` is not your man.  Try `sed`:

```
$ find /lib /lib64 -type f -name '*lib*' | sed 's@/.*/@@;s@\..*$@@'
```

You can pipe to `sort -u` to remove any duplicates.  The below command would be more accurate by using `awk` and `cut` (or `awk` again -- either/or -- `cut` is shorter/prettier, IMHO):

```
$ find /lib /lib64 -type f -name '*lib*' | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | cut -d. -f1 | sort -u
```

Returns:

`20-libgphoto2-6
40-libsane
klibc-P2s_k-gf23VtrGgO2_4pGkQgwMY
libBrokenLocale-2
libSegFault
libacl
libaio
libanl-2
libatasmart
libattr
libaudit
libblkid
libbsd
libbz2
libc-2
libcap
libcgmanager
libcidn-2
libcom_err
libcrypt-2
libcrypto
libdbus-1
libdevmapper
libdl-2
libe2p
libexpat
libext2fs
libfuse
libgcc_s
libgcrypt
libglib-2
libgpg-error
libhistory
libjson-c
libkeyutils
libkmod
liblzma
liblzo2
libm-2
libmemusage
libmount
libncurses
libncursesw
libnewt
libnih
libnih-dbus
libnsl-2
libnss_compat-2
libnss_dns-2
libnss_files-2
libnss_hesiod-2
libnss_nis-2
libnss_nisplus-2
libntfs-3g
libpam
libpam_misc
libpamc
libparted
libpci
libpcprofile
libpcre
libpcsclite
libply
libply-boot-client
libply-splash-core
libply-splash-graphics
libpng12
libpopt
libprocps
libpthread-2
libreadline
libresolv-2
librt-2
libselinux
libsepol
libslang
libss
libssl
libsystemd-daemon
libsystemd-login
libthread_db-1
libtinfo
libudev
libulockmgr
libusb-0
libusb-1
libutil-2
libuuid
libwrap
libz`

Otherwise, you don't need the pipe to `cut` to remove all extensions:

```
$ find /lib /lib64 -type f -name '*lib*' | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | sort -u
```

Returns:

`20-libgphoto2-6.hwdb
40-libsane.rules
klibc-P2s_k-gf23VtrGgO2_4pGkQgwMY.so
libBrokenLocale-2.19.so
libSegFault.so
libacl.so.1.1.0
libaio.so.1.0.1
libanl-2.19.so
libatasmart.so.4.0.5
libattr.so.1.1.0
libaudit.so.1.0.0
libblkid.so.1.1.0
libbsd.so.0.6.0
libbz2.so.1.0.4
libc-2.19.so
libcap.so.2.24
libcgmanager.so.0.0.0
libcidn-2.19.so
libcom_err.so.2.1
libcrypt-2.19.so
libcrypto.so.1.0.0
libdbus-1.so.3.7.6
libdevmapper.so.1.02.1
libdl-2.19.so
libe2p.so.2.3
libexpat.so.1.6.0
libext2fs.so.2.4
libfuse.so.2.9.2
libgcc_s.so.1
libgcrypt.so.11.8.2
libglib-2.0.so.0.4000.0
libgpg-error.so.0.10.0
libhistory.so.6.3
libjson-c.so.2.0.0
libkeyutils.so.1.4
libkmod.so.2.2.5
liblzma.so.5.0.0
liblzo2.so.2.0.0
libm-2.19.so
libmemusage.so
libmount.so.1.1.0
libncurses.so.5.9
libncursesw.so.5.9
libnewt.so.0.52.15
libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
libnih.so.1.0.0
libnsl-2.19.so
libnss_compat-2.19.so
libnss_dns-2.19.so
libnss_files-2.19.so
libnss_hesiod-2.19.so
libnss_nis-2.19.so
libnss_nisplus-2.19.so
libntfs-3g.so.841.0.0
libpam.so.0.83.1
libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
libpamc.so.0.82.1
libparted.so.0.0.1
libpci.so.3.2.1
libpcprofile.so
libpcre.so.3.13.1
libpcsclite.so.1.0.0
libply-boot-client.so.2.1.0
libply-splash-core.so.2.1.0
libply-splash-graphics.so.2.1.0
libply.so.2.1.0
libpng12.so.0.50.0
libpopt.so.0.0.0
libprocps.so.3.0.0
libpthread-2.19.so
libreadline.so.6.3
libresolv-2.19.so
librt-2.19.so
libselinux.so.1
libsepol.so.1
libslang.so.2.2.4
libss.so.2.0
libssl.so.1.0.0
libsystemd-daemon.so.0.0.10
libsystemd-login.so.0.7.1
libthread_db-1.0.so
libtinfo.so.5.9
libudev.so.1.3.5
libulockmgr.so.1.0.1
libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
libutil-2.19.so
libuuid.so.1.3.0
libwrap.so.0.7.6
libz.so.1.2.8`

Comment: thanks for explanation! Now I see the full picture of my problem and solutions to it!