# How can I use two bash commands in -exec of find command? WITH GREP

Tags: grep, find, exec

I would like to do the same as [How can I use two bash commands in -exec of find command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18077/how-can-i-use-two-bash-commands-in-exec-of-find-command) but with grep as the second command. The solutions posted for that prior solution don't work when grep is the second command. Another question [Combination of find and grep command with exec option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234545/combination-of-find-and-grep-command-with-exec-option) inquires about using grep, but all the answers don't use grep.  I think I need grep.

For example,

```
sudo find -D exec . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*" -exec file -N '{}' \; -exec echo 'asdf' \;
```

works fine, but

```
sudo find -D exec . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*" -exec file -N '{}' \; -exec grep "JPEG" {} \;
```

shows no evidence of grep doing anything. How can I force the stdout of the first command to stdin for grep?  If I instead, pipe the file command output to a file and run grep separately on the file it works great:

```
dell@DELL-E6440:~$ rm junk.txt
dell@DELL-E6440:~$ sudo find -D exec . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*" -exec file -N '{}' >> junk.txt \;
dell@DELL-E6440:~$ grep "JPEG" junk.txt
./150120-ssc-proxy~20190508-061623.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 150x150, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1018x1426, frames 3
./avoid-powered-overfight~20190508-061623.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, comment: "Intel(R) JPEG Library, version [2.0.16.48]", baseline, precision 8, 1048x659, frames 3
dell@DELL-E6440:~$
```

but the point is I want to do it on one bash line, and >> doesn't properly flush the file between runs anyhow.

Comment: You don't get any output from `grep` because none of the files you run `grep` on contains the string `JPEG`.  But thu command is definitely running.

Comment: Kusalananda, The test files do have the string JPEG in them - I know because when I leave the grep command off the end, I see them. Why did you assert that they do not have JPEG in them?  The last clip of command lines shows the output dumped to a file and then you can see the file does have the string "JPEG".

Comment: Your `junk.txt` file contains the string `JPEG`, because it contains the output of the `file` command.  The image files do not contain the word `JPEG` themselves (except possibly by coincidence as part of the binary image data, but not in your case). Your `find` commands runs `file` on the files, and then `grep` on the same files.  The `file` command generates the output you redirect into `junk.txt` while the `grep` command that `find` executes does not generate any output.

Comment: @Kusal, ah.. yes. I misread your comment.  The test files do not have the test strings; the output of the file command does. My idea was to convert filenames to best-guess file types, while also dragging the filename along in the text stream so both would be printed on the console by grep.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run `file` on every file and then `grep` the output from `file` for the string `JPEG`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec file {} + | grep JPEG
```

This runs `file` on batches of regular files, producing a stream of result output.  This stream is then filtered by `grep` for lines containing the particular string `JPEG`.  Note that filenames containing newlines would be misrepresented in the output of this pipeline.

Your command in the question would run `grep` on the files themselves, not on the output of the `file` command.  Your `find` command also uses `-iname "*"` which is a no-op since all filenames matches that predicate.

Alternatively, using `bash` to loop over the files in the current directory:

```bash
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

for name in ./*; do
    mimetype=$( file --brief --mime-type "$name" )
    if [[ $mimetype == */jpeg ]]; then
        printf '"%s" is a JPEG file\n' "$name"
    fi
done
```

This would use the MIME-type reported for each file in the current directory by `file` to filter out the names that correspond to JPEG files.

A slightly expanded example:

```bash
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

for name in ./*; do
    mimetype=$( file --brief --mime-type "$name" )
    case $mimetype in
        */jpeg)   printf '"%s" is a JPEG file\n'             "$name" ;;
        */png)    printf '"%s" is a PNG file\n'              "$name" ;;
        image/*)  printf '"%s" is some form of image file\n' "$name" ;;
        *)        printf '"%s" is not an image file\n'       "$name"
    esac
done
```

And finally, using the MIME-type directly in `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c '[[ $(file -b --mime-type "$1") == */jpeg ]]' bash {} \; -print
```

or, more efficiently,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c '
    for pathname do
        [[ $(file -b --mime-type "$pathname") == */jpeg ]] && printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
    done' bash {} +
```

These last two commands will just print out the pathnames corresponding to JPEG images.

Comment: Kusalananda,  You're better than I am with concise batch loops.  Your comment about greping the filenames, rather than the file command output is instructional.  I now see both of my execs get their output from the find command; the first does not feed the second.  Got it.  I need to go learn how the "+" operator changes this.

Comment: @Brian The `+` at the end only means "give me as many files as possible at once". This reduces the number of times the `file` command is actually executed by running it with many files at once (as `file file1 file2 file3 etc`).  The real difference is that `grep` then acts on the _output_ of this.  `grep` is not executed by `find` here, but is a separate step in a pipeline.

Comment: I notice you introduced maxdepth 1.  I wonder if the + has a practical limit either from the find or into the file.  After all, the idea here is that I'm searching every file under possibly the entire root file system.

Comment: @Brian No, you introduced `-maxdepth 1`, so I used it as well to only search on the first level. You may want to read [Understanding the -exec option of \`find\`](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping two commands into the find command wasn't the best idea.  Instead, I unwrapped the two operations from within find and instead sequenced them through pipes.

```
$ sudo find . -type f | file -Nz -f - | grep -f ~/badtypes.txt
```

This now gives me a way of recursing with the file command, and find any types of file that do not belong on the computer, regardless of whether they've been renamed or compressed. I wonder why the file command doesn't naturally have a recurse option.

Comment: _"I wonder why the file command doesn't naturally have a recurse option."_ Command `file` just like `cpio` rely on a **list of filenames**, and `find` is a very flexible way to define files. Where you put `-type f -iname "*"` you can easily add more tests.

Comment: rastafile, Thanks for the ideas about find options.  Yes, it's a pretty capable utility.  However, my wonder thought was about why file (not find) doesn't naturally have a recurse option.

Comment: `file`'s _natural_ recurse option _is_ `find`. Ask the author! He didn't strip the `-r` off, he implemented `-f -`.  In your case this detail does create some confusion, but there are three quite equal solutions, no need to call for a new "file -r". Unlike grep, file cannot pull advantage (?) of `find -exec +` .

Answer (score 0):

Kusa's `...-exec file {} + | grep ...`

Your `find | file -f - | grep`

And also this:

```
]# cat fhs.sh 
#/bin/bash
file -Nz * | grep "magic"

]# find . -exec ./fhs.sh {} +
uout: very short file (no magic)
```

All seem to work, using the same amount of time. Some other variations also work, but they take longer.

---

Normally, the `find ... -exec grep xxx {} +` construct is very efficient (the `+` instead of `\;`). But here, with `file`, you "interfere" with the filenames.

So here, your "flat" (pipeline) approach is OK.

Comment: @ rastafile, you used the phrase "interfere with filenames".  Actually, the filenames are in the output stream from file so grep should find them.  It's just that a *second* exec (the grep one in my case) gets output directly from the find utility, which includes only filename, not the search patterns grep looks for from the file utility output.